Are power and log an inverse to each other? Do they form a group? Is the group abelian?
I noticed that $$a^{\log_a b}=b$$
and
$$\log_a a^b=b$$
So it seems that log followed by power is identity and power followed by log is identity.
How should we formalize this?
Can this be a function and a group?
Is the group abelian?
I am teaching my daughter high school Math and I want her to be able to derive log formula. I sometimes used those 2 formula above to derive pretty much most log formulas.

See here.

$a^x$ and $\log_a(x)$ are called inverse functions from each other like for example $x^2 $ and $\sqrt{x}.$ And you are right:  most rules for log are derived this way.
If you mean with "group" that the two functions are strongly connected  it is a group, but the mathematical definition of group does not apply

$x^2$ and $\sqrt x$ are not inverses. An inverse of some $f$ exists iff $f$ is bijective and $x^2$ is not bijective.

@RandyMarsh They are inverses as functions $[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$.

@Mark true, but then it should be noted as such. The default is that $x^2$ is a function on $\mathbb R$.

@RandyMarsh Indeed, it should. But if the question is about high school math, I can understand why the answer is not very formal. The purpose was mostly to explain the idea.

Unfortunately I can't agree here since even in a less formal setting, i.e. a high-school we teach that $\sqrt{x^2}$ is not equal to $x$ but to $|x|$, but I'll leave it at that

THe way to say this in the abstract terms you are looking for is that the function
$$
x \to a^x
$$
maps the group of nonnegative real numbers (with the group operation multiplication) isomorphically to the group of all real numbers with operation addition.
That map is an isomorphism - its inverse is the map
$$
x \to \log_a x
$$
That's what the two equations say. What makes that bijection a group isomorphism are the "rules for exponents": the product of two exponential expressions corresponds to the sum of their exponents. The corresponding "rule" for logarithms is that the logarithm of a product is the sum of the logarithms.
How you describe this is terms appropriate for your daughter is up to the two of you.
